# How to put 3 elements in priority_queue in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, priority-queue

[image]

I been studying priority_queue in c++ from Leetcode and I found this code from solution
I understand that this is minimum heap but don't understand how is this storing 3 elements to minHeap.

1. is `vector<int>` gets `matrix[r][0]`, `vector<vector<int>>` gets `r` and `greater<>` gets `0`????
2. Why do we need to put `priority_queue<int,vector<int>,greater<int>> minHeap` a `vector<int>` to make Minimum heap?

Comment: From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's look at the meaning of the template arguments in the class of `minHeap`.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

> ```cpp
> template<
>     class T,
>     class Container = std::vector<T>,
>     class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
> ```
>
> **Template parameters**
>
> **T** -   The type of the stored elements. ...
>
> **Container** -   The type of the underlying container to use to store the elements. ...
>
> **Compare** - A Compare type providing a strict weak ordering.

So, for `minHeap`, it contains `vector<int>` objects. It uses a `vector<vector<int>>` as the underlying storage to contain these `vector<int>` objects. And it uses `greater<>` to compare two `vector<int>` objects to decide what order they go in.

---

What does the `greater<>` signify? The `Compare` argument is used to decide which element goes on top. By default, `priority_queue` uses `less<>`, which means that larger elements go on top. By using `greater<>` instead, it flips the direction of the comparison, so smaller elements go on top. This is what makes it a "min" heap.

---

Now, looking at the call to [push](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/push):

> ```cpp
> void push( const value_type& value );
> void push( value_type&& value ); (since C++11)
> ```

`push` is only accepting a single argument, and the argument is of type `value_type`, which in this case is `vector<int>`.

So the line

```cpp
minHeap.push({matrix[r][0], r, 0});
```

Is actually adding a single `vector<int>` to `minHeap`. The values contained in that `vector<int>` are `matrix[r][0]`, `r`, and `0`.